# .htaccess not working

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess

I have done a fresh installation of xampp , after installing the folder containing following `htaccess` file is not showing in my browser.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

it gives 500 error and the server is overloaded

This happens when I am trying to execute the public folder in my zend application.

Please suggest to me whether I have to do any modifications in my xampp for getting my `.htaccess` file to execute correctly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What errors are in the apache error logs?

Comment: have you enabled mod_rewrite module in apache?

Comment: error log in apache is [Tue Mar 22 16:38:46 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] D:/xampp/htdocs/gowtham/test1/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration, referer: http://localhost/gowtham/

Comment: This means mod_rewrite is not enabled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Make sure you've enabled `mod_rewrite` in the Apache configuration file.

2) Add the line `AllowOverride All` to the directory configuration in the Apache config file.

Additionally, unless you have a lot of rewrites, I recommend the following over your current rules.

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: it did not worked in my case: http://superuser.com/questions/473556/how-do-i-install-apache-on-my-ubuntu-12-04-where-it-has-virtualhost

Comment: YumYumYum, I don't see how my answer is at all related to the question you're linking to.