# Cannot remove index.php from my urls in Codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am using codeigniter and when I set up the website I added necessary code in my .htaccess file to remove index.php (default) from my urls. I just happened to replace my public_html folder from a back up file of my website. Since I did that, I cannot get any of the links on home page to work unless insert index.php in the url between the domain name and the rest of the url as in http://www.obsia.com/index.php/contact/ instead of http://www.obsia.com/contact/ and it works. So, in my config file within the application folder, I changed

```
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

and all the links seem to work now. But how do I remove index.php from the URLs.

Here is what my .htaccess code looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction. It will much appreciated.

Regards,
G

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What yo want to do can be done this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
# Static content. Rewrite to - (don't change) and mark as last rule.
RewriteRule !^(index\.php|public|user_guide|robots\.txt|css) - [L]

# Do the rewrite.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However, a slightly better way of doing that is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
# Only do the rewrite under the condition that the requested URL isn't a (real) file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried both and it still gives me 404 error if I remove index.php from the URL. I can delete the entire .htaccess file and it does not seem to make a difference. It seems to me that it is not taking .htaccess file into account at all. Not sure why and what is overriding it.

Comment: Try a file with only

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]  That's a simple test that should display 403 forbidden on **everything**. If that doesn't work, maybe you haven't enabled mod_rewrite in the Apache configuration. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390139/htaccess-not-working/5390747#5390747

Comment: I did try the above test and it still comes up with 404 time each time I click on a link (when index.php is removed from the URL) via home page. It was working before I restored the website files yesterday from a backup that was working as well when I had backed up. I do have access to httpd.conf file to enable mod_rewrite. Is there any other way I can do this?

Comment: I am assuming this is what you meant I should have in the .htaccess file: `RewriteEngine on RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L] AllowOverride All`. This is what the error I get: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. ....... Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: No. AllowOverride All should go into the Apache config file, in the section for the folder in question.

Comment: Alright, I tried the 'slightly better way of doing that' code and that made my pages load with header and footer with the page you are looking for message. Then I changed the 'uri_protocol' from Auto to request uri and that sorted my urls. But I am not sure I understand why it works - would you have any clue?

Comment: Are you using HeaderName/ReadmeName attributes to display information above/below a directory listing?

Comment: sorry i know this is dead but you should also use the !-d along with !-f so that directories are ignores for like images and docs, you can refer to the CI wiki for more info: (solution 3 is the best and my favorite since it works everywhere i have tried it) http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Dreamhost_.htaccess/

Comment: BrandonS: There's absolutely no need to include `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` unless 1) you want directory listings (most people usually go out of their way to disable those) 2) you're mixing URLs consisting of actual URLs with CI, which you probably shouldn't.

Comment: Fffff-! I meant no need to include `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` of course.

Answer (score 2):

there are so many ht access files... In my case i was editing the wrong file... u should edit the file that is inside the project.. for example i work on code igniter and project name was test , so inside test folder i had a htaccess file and inside my application folder ie test/application there was another htaccess file.. i was editing the access file inside the application folder, but i had to edit the file in test folder not test/application/.htaccess.... hope sum 1 finds this useful.. cos i spent half a day to figure this out :(

Cheers
ksp